# Como excluir apenas um determinado dado de um estado React

Tags: javascript, react, jsx

Hoje tenho a seguinte constante:

```
const alunos = [{
 id: 1,
 nome: 'Julia',
 curso: 'Enfermagem',
}, {
 id: 2,
 nome: 'Isabela',
 curso: 'Veterinária'
}]
```

porém eu precisaria apagar apenas o dado do id, que está setado no state e atualizá-lo.

Comment: Thales, acho que você precisa ser um pouco mais claro. Você quer atualizar ou deletar? O que você tentou até agora? Deu algum erro? Porque o que você tentou não está funcionando?

Comment: Acrescentando a resposta do "Douglas Teles" você pode fazer o uso do `map` no lugar do `FOR`. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varra o array e busque pelos IDs, então remova utilizando `delete`

```js
const alunos = [{
 id: 1,
 nome: 'Julia',
 curso: 'Enfermagem',
}, {
 id: 2,
 nome: 'Isabela',
 curso: 'Veterinária'
}];

for (var i =0; i < alunos.length; i++){
      delete alunos[i].id;
}

console.log(alunos);
```

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, sua pergunta está um tanto quanto difícil de entender, talvez até por que você ainda não entende muito bem React.

Você disse que quer apagar um item do 'Estado React'. Isso para mim significa que você deseja apagar de `this.state`, correto? Se for, por qual motivo mostrou uma constante de array com 2 objetos e não o `this.state`?

Além disso, no `this.state` você nunca deleta nada, nem atualiza nada diretamente (this.state.attribute = 'some value'). Você sempre deixa que o React atualize para você através do `this.setState({})`. Por exemplo, para apagar um atributo basta defini-lo como undefined: `this.setState({ foo: undefined })`

Melhore o enunciado de sua dúvida para conseguirmos ajuda-lo mais.

Answer (score 0):

Basta você usar o método `filter` para manter na lista somente as propriedades que tenham um ID **diferente** daquele que você deseja excluir.

Por exemplo:

```js
const state = [{
  id: 1,
  nome: 'Julia',
  curso: 'Enfermagem',
}, {
  id: 2,
  nome: 'Isabela',
  curso: 'Veterinária'
}]

// ID que desejamos excluir:
const id = 1

const newState = state.filter((data) => data.id !== id)

console.log(newState)
```

Para saber mais sobre esse método, leia a documentação [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) no MDN.

Answer (score 0):

Você pretende deletar o item que está guardado no estado?
Poderia:

```
 const alunos = [{
 id: 1,
 nome: 'Julia',
 curso: 'Enfermagem',
}, {
 id: 2,
 nome: 'Isabela',
 curso: 'Veterinária'
}]
 const index = alunos.findIndex( i => i.id == this.state.alunos.id);
 alunos.splice(index, 1);
 // Ou se for somente o id 
 delete alunos[index].id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Como o nosso amigo Gleidson Henrique Comentou sua pergunta não esta clara mas eu vou tentar ajudar pelo que eu entendi.

**Você tem uma constante dentro do Estado Certo ?**
Tome como exemplo esse meu estado button

{this.state.buttons.map((button, index) =>
        delete button[index]
)}

Espero ter ajudado